# Regex including one space

Tags: regex

I need to find a regex that will match any string, at least 6 characters long, including only one space, but the space can't be the first or the last character.
I tried many combinations of \S and \s but I am now stuck.
Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Including one or zero spaces:

```
^(?=.{6,})(\S+\s?\S+)$
```

If you meant that it must have a space then you should remove the `?` in `\s?`. This will only work in a regex engine that supports positive lookaheads and recognizes the `\s` and `\S` sequences. [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=%5E%28?=.%7B6,%7D%29%28%5CS%2b%5Cs?%5CS%2b%29$&input=*%20@!#%5E)

Comment: @Raffaeu works in Javascript. Maybe you grabbed it in between an edit.

Answer (score -1):

preg_match_all("/[^\s][.*]{6,}[^\s]/", $str, $matches);

Comment: Downvoted because that doesn't work. It matches a string like `x..***..*.*y` without any spaces, and can only have `.`s and `*`s in the string other than the first and last character. It must also be at least 8 characters long. I will remove my downvote if it is fixed.